# Using R to filter comments for text mining

Tags: r, text-mining

I am using R and relatively new to programming so any help will be appreciated.

I am text mining for a survey and would like to filter comments with a combination of words. The data set has been read from a csv file.

I want to filter the comments that contain the words "abroad" and "charges"

I am using the grepl function to recognise the pattern with in the comments.
I have managed to filter the data in the Comment section which has the words
"abroad" and "charges" by using the following code:

```
ac <- filter(data, grepl("abroad|charges", Comment))

  ac$Comment
```

This returns comments with words "abroad" and "charges" but it returns comments which can either have "abroad" or "charges". I would like a combination of both words. I tried replacing | with & but this does not work.

I have also tried subset:

```
ac <- subset(data, Comment %in% c("abroad", "charges"))

ac$Comment
```

None of these return the desired results. Am  I missing something obvious? How can I view comments that contain only certain words in them. So if I further wanted to explore my text I could try to find the combination of "abroad" and "charges" and "expensive."

Thanks any help would be great.

Comment: It is better to show few lines of data using `dput`.  If you need combination of words, use `&` i.e. `filter(data, grepl("abroad", Comment) & grepl('charges', Comment))`

Comment: It wont' work in that way

Comment: Thanks akrun, that worked I was trying: `ac <- filter(data, grepl("abroad" & "charges", Comment))`, just out of interest would I be able to do this through **subset**? In future I will show the data as well.

Comment: You can use `subset` as well.  with the same command replacing `filter` with `subset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a double `grep` with `&` operator inside the `filter` and it should only be `TRUE` for words that contain both 'abroad' and 'charges' in the `string`.

```
 filter(data, grepl("abroad", Comment) & grepl('charges', Comment))
```